How to center a group of square divs aligned left with no extra space
I have a ul of squares with fixed h and w, I need them to be aligned to the left when wrapping on a new line. They are inside a container and this container is centered in the app viewport.
I've used flex-wrap but when the squares wraps the ul becomes the width of the container, resulting in extra space on the right of the squares and messing up the centering.
How can I make it so the ul stays the width of the content?


body {
  background-color:black;

}

.app-viewport {
  text-align: right;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height:100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.resize-effect {
  width: 700px;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 0.1rem;
}

ul li {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.wrapper {
  gap: 4rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
}

.square {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: gray;
}
<div class="app-viewport">
  
  <div class="resize-effect">    
  <ul class="wrapper">
    <li>
      <div class="square"></div>
    </li>
       <li>
      <div class="square"></div>
    </li>
        <li>
      <div class="square"></div>
    </li>
        <li>
      <div class="square"></div>
    </li>
        <li>
      <div class="square"></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
      <p>Purple wrapper should be centered and fit the content (no extra space on the right)</p>
  </div>
  
</div>



Expected Result (hardcoded):


body {
  background-color:black;

}

.app-viewport {
  text-align: right;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height:100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.resize-effect {
  width: 700px;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 0.1rem;
}

ul li {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.wrapper {
  gap: 4rem;
  width: 465px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.square {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: gray;
}
<div class="app-viewport">
  
  <div class="resize-effect">    
  <ul class="wrapper">
    <li>
      <div class="square"></div>
    </li>
       <li>
      <div class="square"></div>
    </li>
        <li>
      <div class="square"></div>
    </li>
        <li>
      <div class="square"></div>
    </li>
        <li>
      <div class="square"></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  
</div>




Not sure I understood correctly but you may be looking for justify-content:space-between; (instead of left) applied to the wrapper.
